# How to change Korge NinePatch width and height?

Tags: kotlin, korge

I am developing a game using Korge game engine.

I tried to change the width of a NinePatch, which is attached to a FixedSizeContainer
but when running this code,NinePatch image's sides getting distorted .

```
     val scoreBg=ninePatch(resourcesVfs["gamescreen/scorebg.9.png"].readNinePatch(),
                    40.0,30.0){}
                   .position(40.0,40.0) //<-- rendering correctly

     val score=text("0",font = font).centerOn(scoreBg)
        
     val scoreUpdateFun:(score:Int)->Unit = {
            val text="$it"
            val len=text.length
            scoreBg.width=30+len*10.0//<---- changes width but distorts sides
            score.text="$it"
        }

    scoreUpdateFun(100)
```

What is the correct method to change the width/height ?

**Update-1**

By the Korge [docs](https://korlibs.soywiz.com/korge/views_standard/#ninepatch), I was using extended version of the NinePatch, that uses the KorIM’s NinePatchBitmap32, that is compatible with the IntelliJ 9-patch bitmap.

When I switched to normal `NinePatch` from  `NinePatchEx` it is working fine.
But I can not use 9-patch bitmap directly

I changed code to

```
val scoreBg=ninePatch(
    atlas["scorebg2.png"],40.0,30.0,
    53.0/119.0, 47.0/101.0, 52.0/119.0, 47.0/101.0)
    .position(40.0,40.0)
```

**Update-2**

I found an open [issue](https://github.com/korlibs/korge/issues/97#event-3390800579) related to my problem

My game is using Korge Version **1.13.9.0**

Comment: Yes, there is an open issue. Just prioritized it. So going to fix it asap. :+1:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fixed already. You can check a working sample here:

9-patch image: https://github.com/korlibs/korge-samples/blob/master/ninepatch/src/commonMain/resources/image.9.png
Sample updating the patch moving the mouse: https://github.com/korlibs/korge-samples/blob/master/ninepatch/src/commonMain/kotlin/main.kt

Comment: Thanks for updating. I have one more question, How can I pack a 9-patch image with its patch info to an Atlas ?

Comment: That's doesn't directly supported I think. But you can create a feature request at github and we will implement it.